# mvc 4 + iis7.5 application stop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

It's the first time that I write here so I hope to be very clear !
I've a deployed mvc application on iis 7.5. In the application_start it starts to do some operation like download files on a fixed interval.
I've access to windows server 2008 by remote desktop on a virtual machine. 
The problem is that when I logout from this virtual machine, the application seems to stop and it is not downloading anymore anything 'till I don't start once another time the application.

Is it normal or do I've some kind of problem in my configuration ?

I want that the application start just one time and cycle that kind of operations without stops..

Answer (score 1):

On default application pool settings, this is normal (assuming you have low traffic to your site).  The app pool will shutdown after a set inactivity period and take your downloader offline with it.  I believe the default is 20 minutes of inactivity.

Here's some info on configuring the timeout.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx

And here's some info about configuring IIS to auto start and always run (to somewhat emulate a windows service environment) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Here are some of the risks and workarounds associated with running long running processes under asp.net  http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: You said that is normal to use `application_start` to start periodic download action and same time you said that pool shutdown after 20 min inactivity.. To my mind it is bad idea and better idea to create separate service for this.

Comment: It's normal to have the long running process die under default settings on a web server.  In general, you try to avoid running long running processes on a web server.  However, if running a windows service or workflow isn't an option, those links will allow it to work.

Comment: Just updated the answer with some of the risks associated with long running processes under asp.net

Comment: I browse throw these articles that you provided. It is interested. But to my mind lucio should rethink twice before starts to use this approach.

Comment: I agree, I would recommend to avoid long running processes inside asp.net whenever possible.  However, I understand that people sometimes have extenuating circumstances which I probably don't have a full view of.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind it isn't good idea to implement downloading in application_start (Check more [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) about lifetime in asp.net). You need to implement some kind of service for this purpose. Could you specify your target for detailed answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I wanna that my application is always active, also when I logout from the virtual machine..

Comment: why don't u think is a good idea? Application_start it must be occur just once time for the life-cycle. I just expect that this "life-cycle" is longer 'till the app-recycle..

Comment: What are you doing in this method?

Comment: Ok. Try to add logging functionality and you will be able to see in which place your code stops to work.

Comment: I'm downloading file from different kind of suppliers. My code stops when I logout from the remote desktop :)